# How to bind tooltips to this html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I have this html element when `console.log` them in my code.

```
<span id="stamps[12]" class="stamps value  widget-data  tooltipstered" data-value="0.00" data-toggle="tooltip">0.00</span>
```

This is how I do call tooltipster.But its not working.

```
$($(htmlData)).find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(v){
                console.log(this);
                 $(this).tooltipster();
             });
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Yes Its worked for me! thanks. @Dekel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the content of the `tooltipster` to be taken from `data-*` attribute, you need to set it inside the `tooltipster` constructor (use the `content` attribute).

Here is an example:

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(v){
  console.log(this);
  $(this).tooltipster({
    content: $(this).data('value')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<span id="stamps[12]" class="stamps value  widget-data  tooltipstered" data-value="0.00" data-toggle="tooltip">0.00</span>
<br />
<span id="stamps[13]" class="stamps value  widget-data  tooltipstered" data-value="12.23" data-toggle="tooltip">12.23</span>
```

Comment: @dhruvjadia happy to help :)